# MySQl. How would you write this query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My current query is not returning the correct values.  My database is full of logs, each log contains a code.  I'm  looking  for 4 codes specifically, say (100, 200, 300, 400).

I need to know how many times a certain session_id activated only 1 code, 2 of the codes, 3 of the codes, and all 4 of the codes.

The query will be run 4 different times taking in a different parameter each time (1,2,3,4).

So if there is a log with each of the codes with the same session_id that will be +1 when I run the query for 4.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can get all four counts in one pass:

```
SELECT codecount, COUNT(*) AS sessioncount
FROM (
    SELECT session_id, COUNT(DISTINCT code) AS codecount
    FROM log
    WHERE code IN (100, 200, 300, 400)
    GROUP BY session_id
) AS c
GROUP BY codecount;
```

Comment: The OP said they want a count of a count -- how many sessions had a certain number of matches.  So codecount ranges from 1-4, and sessioncount is how many sessions had each subtotal of number of codes matched.

Comment: Doesn't `codecount` need to be added to the main SELECT clause as well?

Comment: @AndriyM, you're right, that would sure be helpful!  :)  I'll edit that above.